# ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_12 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, seq2seq

I am working on seq2seq model, and I want to use the embedding layer given in [Keras Blog Bonus FAQ](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html). Here is my code, where num_encoder_tokens is 67 and num_decoder_tokens is 11.
[image]

I am getting the issue shown in figure.
[image]

Can anyone help me with reshaping the output_shape of embedding layer or input shape of LSTM as I have no idea how to do it.